# UITextField text style get automatically changed

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` and when I try to setText on that `UITextField` the font size and style changes automatically. I only initialize the `textField` once and later on I change the frame (size remains the same while origin changes). is there any particular reason for this. May be I have missed setting a property to keep text style consistance. I tried searching for an solution, but could not find any information after 7 hours.

[image]

[image]

Comment: i think  your custom font not added properly

Comment: I actually did not add any font. I was using the default font for textfield. Would you suggest adding a custom font could fix this issue ?

Comment: no no I think r u used the custom font can u sent your project I will check and tell to you

Comment: unfortunately I cant send you the project. This get triggered only when I setText

Comment: oh k bro , we will try to resolve , check attribute you set correctly or missed

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setText

use setAttributedText and use same font and font size to prepare the attributed text.